# Rails bulk objects creation and validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have and application on Ruby on Rails 4. I have controller which receives data from client and creates bulk objects. So some of objects can be created and stored if data from these object is correct and other (invalid) object should not be created and returned to client for further fixes.

My model class (contains name and date):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :date, presence: true
end
```

My Controller:

```
PersonsController
    def create_multiple
        valid_persons = []
        invalid_persons = []
        all_persons_params = get_all_persons_params #just extract it from params
        all_persons_params.each.do |one_person_params|
            person = Person.new one_person_params
            if person.valid?
                valid_persons << person
            else
               invalid_persons << person
            end
        end
        process_valid_persons #store them
        process_invalid_persons invalid_persons #redirect to persons modifications page to make user to fix errors (if !invalid_persons.empty?)
    end
    def process_invalid_persons (invalid_persons)
        flash[:invalid_persons] = invalid_persons
        redirect_to ...
    end
end
```

Finally i try to show errors in my view:

```
<%
    @invalid_persons.each do |invalid_person|
        invalid_person.errors
    end
%>
```

And i get error on line `invalid_person.errors` in my view **undefined method `errors' for #Hash:0x007f99d0ca2788**

So it seams that I can't create object if its params are invalid and ruby returns hash map instead of object. So is there any way to create object in invalid params case? And get validation errors to show them to user?

Thx

Comment: I didn't see you pass `invalid_persons` to anywhere. And why in view it is `@invalid_orders`?

Comment: Hi, i do it in process_invalid_persons (updated my question)

Comment: `invalid_persons` is a local variable which only live inside `create_multiple` method, isn't it? inside `process_invalid_persons` method, `invalid_persons` will be nil.

Comment: sry, updated my question, i think that the problem is in my redirect to the page with invalid orders, i try to pass invalid_orders in flash scope to error_processing action of my controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails 4. Can i pass objects through flash scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803020/ruby-on-rails-4-can-i-pass-objects-through-flash-scope)