# Ruby on Rails 4. Can i pass objects through flash scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller and need to pass objects which validation fail to another controller action to process them and show to user:

```
class PersonController
    def save_persons
        invalid_persons = ... #array of Person.new objects
        flash[:invalid_persons] = invalid_persons
        redirect_to action: :fix_errors
    end
    def fix_errors
        invalid_persons = flash[:invalid_persons]
        invalid_persons.each do |invalid_person|
            puts invalid_person.errors #here i get exception!
        end
    end
end
```

When i try to   `puts invalid_person.errors` i get error: `undefined method errors for #Hash:0x007fd594e79098>`. It seems that rails transform my objects array to some hash

Can you suggest me, what is the right way to pass some object through flash?

Comment: Why not render the `fix_errors` view, rather than attempt to pass a load of data through the flash?

Comment: Wow it works, really thx!

Comment: flash should just be used for messages anyway:  use `session` if you want to store something temporarily, although it's usually not great practice.